# Which is the faster way to add single char to String in Java: a char(str + 'c'), or String(str + "c")?

Tags: java, string, optimization, types

I couldn't find anything online about this topic, though I apologize if that's because I'm not sure how to word this question effectively.

My theory would be String(str + "c") would be faster, due to JVM not having to convert char to String first before concatenation. Char(str + 'c') could be faster due to char being a simpler datatype. But I wouldn't be surprised if JDK optimizes it properly anyway at compile time, making it irrelevant. Anyone else know the answer to this?

Comment: For a few appends, it really doesn't matter. For a lot of appends, use `StringBuilder`.

Comment: you understand that "c" is not a char? It is a String that is made up of one char.

Comment: [Race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Stultuske, yes "c" is a string, I meant if I wanted to append a single static character to a string, should I represent it as a string("c"), or a char('c')? For mainly speed, but also code etiquette.

Comment: Jorn, StringBuilder is good, but this post was more for curiosity about these 2 methods for just 1 or 2 concatenations.

Comment: Your reasoning is flawed because Java doesn't need to convert a char to a string; but, conversely, it needs to handle chars individually *anyway*, so if you concatenate a string (even one of length 1) it needs to iterate through all the chars in it to concatenate them.

Comment: Konrad Rudolph, so if any speed diff is yielded at all, it would be from using a char('c'), correct? Edit: accidentally hit enter halfway through.

Comment: @Jorn don’t use `StringBuilder`, unless you’re performing concatenation in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't make any assumptions about which is faster, and how it works will depend on JDK you use and where `str` is declared. Consider this sample compiled in Eclipse JDK20:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    final String a = "hello";
    final String b = "world";

    final String c = a+"c";
    final String d = b+'c';

    final String e = args[0]+"c";
    final String f = args[1]+'c';

    System.out.format("%s - %s - %s - %s", c, d, e, f);
}
```

If I open the .class file in IDE decompile, it shows that `c` and `d` were generated in by compiler:

```
 6  ldc <String "helloc"> [20]
 8  astore_3 [c]
 9  ldc <String "worldc"> [22]
11  astore 4 [d]
```

As `args` isn't known at compile time, the code contains equivalent of

```
String e = new StringBuilder(args[0]).append("c").toString();
String f = new StringBuilder(args[1]).append('c').toString();
```

Which is:

```
13  new java.lang.StringBuilder [24]
16  dup
17  aload_0 [args]
18  iconst_0
19  aaload
20  invokestatic java.lang.String.valueOf(java.lang.Object) : java.lang.String [26]
23  invokespecial java.lang.StringBuilder(java.lang.String) [32]
26  ldc <String "c"> [35]
28  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.append(java.lang.String) : java.lang.StringBuilder [37]
31  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.toString() : java.lang.String [41]
34  astore 5 [e]
```

and

```
36  new java.lang.StringBuilder [24]
39  dup
40  aload_0 [args]
41  iconst_1
42  aaload
43  invokestatic java.lang.String.valueOf(java.lang.Object) : java.lang.String [26]
46  invokespecial java.lang.StringBuilder(java.lang.String) [32]
49  bipush 99
51  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.append(char) : java.lang.StringBuilder [45]
54  invokevirtual java.lang.StringBuilder.toString() : java.lang.String [41]
57  astore 6 [f]
```

Don't rely on above, it might change across JDKs as improvements are added, and don't bother changing code between either type of concatenation. Your performance issues are likely to be in I/O or database or network issues.

Note comments below.

Comment: You are using Eclipse, aren’t you? Because `javac` would [use a single `invokedynamic` instruction to perform the concatenation](https://tio.run/##dZFBa8MgAIXv@xUPYTShRrbz2I47F9pbycGo6cxMFDUZY/S3O5O2o9DuoB6@9x6PZ8cnXnXyMyVheAjYqRDx8wC4sTFaIEQe8zNZLdFzPRTb6PVw2Nfg/hBKLFqg1QM3ODFwvIJ8KGMsebmlzUy/rDcy01ssMuZrIu5ZZWbNeiVW94xqNuZO@6f6H3t7UTzXVyHb7xBVz@wYWWt9z2NBHgMqXF@EQlBICkXRlnP0MZ/zNqcFujwkG6M2LDjNdtaajbeTlsqzXEK@ax9y8qxypFwcANPtxqughlg4VG9wzI954b9C9FJOeU9BKpF7kPmHSHkucUwpLUunZdFf) The `format` operation is the most expensive here…

Comment: @Holger Yes this was from Eclipse to save time, and I see that `javac` is handling with invokedynamic. Another good reason not to favour one way over other.